# NPM install git repo fails because it uses my mac username instead of 'git'

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, npm-install

I'm trying to install something from a private repo, I'm running:

```
npm i git+ssh://git.remoterepo.net/somerepo.git
```

I have a SSH key at `~/.ssh/id_rsa` which has no passphrase and it's configured at my remote git repo (gitlab).

However each time it prompts me:

> [MAC_USER]@git.remoterepo.net's password:

It should be using **git@git.remoterepo.net** (git username). If I SSH with the *git* username then I can log in:

> ssh git@git.remoterepo.net

But if I do `ssh [MAC_USER]@git.remoterepo.net` then it prompts me for a password and can't. I've tried `npm i git@git+ssh://git.remoterepo.net/somerepo.git` but it still uses the wrong username..

**How can I make npm install use the git username instead of my mac login one?**

I've also tried HTTPS but no luck (hangs or gives 401 Unauthorized).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `npm i git+ssh://git@git.remoterepo.net/somerepo.git`.

Search for `git@` in https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install